# Getting following Error Message when you run code Using TFS Build

Tags: tfs-2015, devops

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYBRD.jpg)The Path Error I have Got

[image]

Getting Path error when running C# Code through TFS , Not able to find CSV path from which we are picking data for Execution

Note: Deploying & Running Code through Virtual Machine

Comment: Please add your codes

Comment: Did you check if the path exists on your virtual machine?

Comment: @Simon D. I have checked the path which got in error not exists on my machine..

Comment: That is the point, you need to deploy all required files with your project. In this case you should put the csv-file in your smoke test project and then reference it via relative path instead of the absolute path or user folder.

Comment: There is also an error in the linked code snipped:
You call substring on a string, but you do not use the returned value, i.e. you should use
    path = path.Substring(0,...)
instead of just calling
   path.Substring(0,...)
because Substring does not change the original string.

Answer (score 0):

First, please try to build your code **manually** on the Virtual Machine to see if it works.

Second, double check if the path and the file exists on your virtual machine.

Third, ensure that the "**Project Collection Build Service Accounts"** group and "**Project Build Service** (TEAM FOUNDATION)" user have appropriate version control rights, such as *Read* and *Label*. Make sure that Inheritance is set to On. Usually the get path error may related to a permission issue.